# Microsoft Access reporting -GROUPBY

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I'm trying to build a report in microsoft access. I have a company name called "FRPP" and I need to display number of employees, etc. The issue is, I have many subdivisions of FRPP that are in different locations. So I have:

```
FRPP - ASIA
FRPP - EUROPE
FRPP - AFRICA
FRPP - SOUTH AMERICA
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is GROUPBY by 'FRPP'. How would I do that? So I only have one instance of FRPP with a Employees: SUM(employees).

Comment: Can you be more specific about your table structure which contains the companies.  In particular is `FRPP - ASIA` a company name?

Comment: @akc42 Yes, basically I have a unique ID for each company subdivision (FRPP - ASIA, FRPP-AFRICA, etc). All data is in one table.  What I'm trying to do is summarize the company and display total information for the company as a whole. So I'm trying to GROUPBY the company names (FRPP) and display is as FRPP - and also, I will be doing sum of Employees, Qtr1, Qtr2, Qtr3 revenues, and other stuff, I know how to do everything else, i'm just not sure how to group the company names, because they all have subdivision names (-ASIA, AFRICA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I normally do all this sort of thing in my SQL Server backend, so not 100% sure it will work in Access, but try something like

```
SELECT SUM(Employees), LEFT(CompanyName,4) AS MainCompany FROM Company GROUP BY LEFT(CompanyName,4)
```

If company names are all different lengths you will have to work out a way to calculate how much should be in the `Left` function (Use `Instr` to get the index of a space?)

Comment: Yes I actually did this and it works. I went by the first four letters:  FRPP:iff(left([compName],4)="FRPP","FRPP",""), and I did a sum for everything else and its looking good

Answer (score 1):

In the Report Design Tools, on the Design tab, there is a button for Group & Sort.  Click that, and then click on the Add A Group button that appears on the bottom of your form.  Group by your Unique ID and add that to the Header section of the form.  Add each field you want into the Detail section, and change the formulas to

```
=Sum([YourFieldName])
```

Change YourFieldName above to whatever your actual field name is.

Comment: I need to summarize everything in one line, I don't need to show each subdividion. If i include it in detail it will show me each subdivision seperately. I want them ALL together. I need to group by FRPP-North, FRPP-SOUTH, FRPP-ASIA so it only shows FRPP